# Is it possible to covert JSON to java bean with @RequestBody without any third party library

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a AJAX request with data in json format like:

```
["name":"Some Name",
  "address":{"id":1, "street":"some street"}]
```

and Java Bean would be look like:

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  private Address address;

  //getters and setters
}

class Address {
  private int id;
  private String street;

  //getters and setters
}
```

is it possible to use `@RequestBody` in handler method to get `Person` without using any third party libraries like: Gson, Jackson etc. if yes how?

Comment: yes, write your own json to java object mapper.

Comment: @DwB thanks I will go with Jackson..

Comment: @downvoters please leave a comment so that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, neither Java nor Spring comes with a JSON mapper. You could write your own, and it wouldn't be a third-party library anymore. But I don't think that's a good idea. What's wrong with Jackson?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No I just wanted to know that spring provides any json mapper classes.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

spring WILL use third party library - I mean it has to be on classpath, but you dont have to write any mapping code by yourself for simple cases as you have shown. Just be sure to really add setters and default constructors to both entities and it should work.